# How to test rgbdslam without a kinect?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to test rgbdslam, but I havenot a kinect.

I have seen:
If you want to test rgbdslam without kinect, download a sequence from http://cvpr.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/download and use "rosbag play <filename.bag>". Make sure to set the appropriate topics (i.e. clear the "topic_points" parameter and set topic_image_mono to /camera/rgb/image_color). Felix Endres (Jan 23 '12)

But I can't quite understand. More detailed steps and any preconditions
?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44587/how-to-test-rgbdslam-without-a-kinect?/) by [seanbyxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/3252/seanbyxm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-09-26**:
Please add the correct tags to your question, or it is likely to be missed (and remain un-answered).

**Comment by [RossK](https://answers.ros.org/users/3194/rossk/) on 2012-09-26**:
I answered this question comprehensively but it didn't seem to show up :(  Short answer is that these parameters are set correctly for the bag files from that dataset, you shouldn't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer is you do not have to do anything in this case.

Long answer:

He is referring to the ros parameters for RGBDSLAM.  These may be set in a launch file or by editing parameter_server.cpp.  The relevant parameters in the case are:

"topic_image_mono" - Topic for the camera image (/camera/rgb/image_color)

"camera_info_topic" - Topic for the camera information (camera/rgb/camera_info)

"topic_image_depth" - Topic for the depth image (camera/depth/image)

"topic_points" - Topic for the pointclouds (camera/rgb/points) Leave this empty, read further

These can be set by making a copy of the launch file rgbdslam_sample_config.launch and editing the relevant fields.

In this case the defaults for these topics are the same as the topics for the bag files in this data set, and therefore it should just work.  If "topic_points" is empty then RGBDSLAM will reconstruct the point clouds from color and depth images.  In this case it is necessary to do so as the bag files do not come with this topic.  This is because the pointcloud topic is far less space efficient than having separate color and depth image topics.

---

Originally posted by [RossK](https://answers.ros.org/users/3194/rossk/) with karma: 141 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/18843/weiwei/) on 2014-08-31**:
I followed your answer and get the right result in the first 3 seconds. However, the bag file I downloaded from [link text](http://cvpr.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/download) which is about 30 seconds,  when I run rosbag play --clock XXX.bag, the bag file only run in the first 3 seconds.